# Google Sheet Importrange script need

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help with a script or any other setting to copy from one file to another. IMPORTRANGE gladly good. In the main file in which the data is entered, I have divided by rows A, B, C, where cells for A go A2, A5, A8, .. for B go B3, B6, B9, for C go C4, C7, C10 and so on. It ends with A86, B87 and C88. I now have to make 3 separate files that will pull separately for A, separately for B, and  for C. The problem is that they are in the main file in every third place.
So far, I've been working on entering the formula = IMPOTRANGE ("addresstofile", "sheetname!A2") in the first cell, and then going to = IMPOTRANGE ("addresstofile", "sheetname!A5") in the next cell,etc.. Is there any easier way because I waste a lot of time like this?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `In the main file in which the data is entered, I have divided by rows A, B, C, where cells for A go A2, A5, A8, .. for B go B3, B6, B9, for C go C4, C7, C10 and so on. It ends with A86, B87 and C88. I now have to make 3 separate files that will pull separately for A, separately for B, and for C. The problem is that they are in the main file in every third place.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? And, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: Your goal isn't clear to me either. Are you trying to import *one column* of data only? So in your first destination sheet, you want *one column* that contains every third cell from Col A of the source sheet starting at cell A2; in the 2nd destination sheet, you want *one column* that contains every third cell from Col A of the source sheet starting at cell A3, etc.? It would help if you include a link to the source sheet, so we can see the data setup. And to be sure, is the original data going to a *separate spreadsheet*? Or is it just going to different sheets within the *same spreadsheet*?

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do is in Column A you want the values from "addresstofile" for A2, A5, A8... and in Column B B3, B6, B9 etc.  Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry all for late answer. Here is picture to show you what I mean. Im sorry, i made a mistake in question and i hope this is more clearer.
https://imgur.com/uWn4LaA

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

One way to do this is to use multiple sheets.

Sheet1 developes the cell address I want to extract.

Sheet2 is an IMPORTRANGE of the entire sheet from the other spreadsheet

Sheet3 is the resulting page using INDIRECT

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]

**Sheet3 (Results)**

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Here is picture to show you what I mean. Im sorry, i made a mistake in question and i hope this is more clearer.
https://imgur.com/uWn4LaA

Comment: I guess I don't know why my example doesn't show you how to build a table of addresses using simple cut and paste. One importrange to import all the data and then indirect to get the particular value from the data table.